# How to convert this file into PNG

Tags: conversion, encoding, utf-8, cryptography, ascii

I have a file with no extension (as far as I can tell) that consists of special symbols. (File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h9MuUDfDtGEneEzZMNKLKWwY7JjZlBTS/view?usp=sharing)

Here're a couple of the **very first lines** of the file:

```
123123123123123213

âPNG


IHDR»»≠XÆûsRGBÆŒÈgAMA±è¸a    pHYsöúˇ•IDATx^Ñ˝tïY∫-Û…=Á‹snü€›’’ÂU@·Ó.¡"ê@<!ƒHB‹=@ wwww/ ©*™
wwBÇ/ÈÓ˘œ˘l^öæˇ¯«?kº˛ÓΩ…3◊ús≠g≠UÂ˛ΩJ¸ÚÚoxˆÙ€>∏ˇ/_¸éﬂ~˝ÂÔ∂èOüÒ˙Ø«ìß/ÒÏ˘Øx¯Ë)*?«Ûgø⁄}zÓvŸ]<|wÔ<ƒ£áOÒ∏Ú9n›¨∞{nﬁ(«ì«/€Øˇ∞˚uüŒÎ}Üé_<ˇÕû”±ﬁW˘Ëô}'Áúûªw˜ë]≥Ô¸‰%û>xâóè«/O„Ûø€;Ó›Øƒµ[e∏Y^Åß/AÂ≥Áx¸‰<¨ƒ”«|Á~Á'ø‚7ﬁ_˘Ëπ˝ûøÒg>©|å;e∑‚·=<)ø…˜p„¯OX7k<fï‰aRN"&d∆aZnVå(¬§ÙXÖ˜FAò∑m
```

The task is to tell what picture it represents and as far as I understand this is encoded PNG or APNG file. I tried online converters TXT to PNG, converted the content into HEX code and then tried converting HEX into PNG but nothing seem to work. How can I convert (decode) this file into a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics you'll get a rough idea of the format.  Opening the file you have in a hex editor shows:
[image: File provided]

If you look at a typical PNG file you have:

[image: PNG reference]
So we can see the additional string at the start of the file.  You can use a hex editor to remove the characters prior to the "89 50 4E 47".  Note the "Magic Number" on the Wikipedia page.

Once you save the modified file back out as a PNG, you can open it in a browser for example.

A magic mime file can also be useful for such tasks.  You can find PNG in here:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/file/file-23/file/magic/magic.mime

Comment: Thank you, I knew that PNG can be represented in hex format but didn't know how to convert it back. Turns out it's simple) Appreciate the help!